# I saw a Jinn while I was sleeping!

Tags: jinn, dream

Salaam,

I am a Muslim and have been ever since I was born. A few days ago I was in my room heading to sleep. I sleep in pitch darkness. During the night I woke up from a nightmare which was to do with a Jinn entering my cat (my cat died 6 years ago btw).

After I woke up in the middle of the night, I was frightened so I switched on the passage light and opened my door to allow the light to come into my room. I then started to slowly drift to sleep. As I was close to deep sleep, I turned to my left side to sleep.

As I turned, my eyes opened briefly and that's when I saw this dark figure enter my room. It came is so quick and did not have any human features (no face). Just a pure black figure! It came in my room and stood right in front of me. Then I couldn't open my eyes or move! I was in sleep paralysis. I heard it say something but I didn't understand. It said something like "don't worry" and I somehow feel as if it touched me. Was definitely evil! I did not feel any goodness from it, and I felt an evil presence even before I went to sleep.

I then was able to move and I ran to my parents room.

Now my question is, what do I do if I encounter a Jinn? What will happen next? Is this just a one off? Is someone doing black magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wsalam,

Actually Jinn (bad ones) do harm people. Islam provides many ways to counter them and deal wit them.

- If you see a jinn, then you must recite Ayat ul kursi in loud voice immediately, and continue to recite it until he is gone. better to recite last 2 verses of Quran as well when you see such things.
- Never fear them (yes, the more you fear them, the more power they have over you (it is practically proven).
- These things only try to frighten you, and if you get frighten,then they can control you,harm you. Dont let it happen. Have faith in Allah that it is the same creator,who made these beings. their evilness cannot harm you in any way, unless Allah wishes.
- To avoid anything like this to happen again,you must recite the daily morning and evening supplications. Here is link to them. Also, you must do the supplications before sleeping. 
  link: http://www.islamicbulletin.org/free_downloads/prayer/daily_supplications.pdf
- To make these things run away and never come to your house, you must recite surah baqara Daily, all day , in your house. you can play a recitation as well as it is proven from Hadith, that when Surah baqara is recited, the devil cannot withstand it.
- These things get attracted to Dirt and filth. the more you remain clean, and remain in wuzoo, wear clean clothes, the more they hate to come close to you or a place, which is clean fully. Also, they hate fragrance and perfumes but love the bad smell.

Comment: Jazakallah for your answer Hamza. Very detailed and easy to understand Alhamdulillah! I need to download Surah Baqara' on my phone and play it out loud. Then inshallah these encounters will not happen again.

Comment: The only thing I wanted to add to your answer is this... Qur'an [43:36](http://quran.com/43/36)

Comment: Inalillahi Wa'Ina Ilahi Raji'oon! So was a devil in my room not a Jinn??!!

Comment: @zain.ali: please follow the link i added and also please upvote my answer , and yes, those are devils. dont be surprised, they are everywhere. they live like we live

Comment: @HamzaIslam I shall follow the link :) But I am unable to up-vote your answer as I do not have enough reputation (I need 15+). But when I do I will certainly up-vote your response. In the meantime, I marked it as the answer.

Comment: Those people, who pray 5 times a day, recite Quran as much as they can, all day. do the zikr of Allah, morning,evening, and night. no evil can harm them... (unless if Allah wishes them to be harmed to test them or for expitation of the sins)